# How to debug a custom built .apk (via ant/build.xml) in Eclipse? and can I get this to happen when I push the Eclipse run/debug button?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build.xml

I have an android project in Eclipse.

I have produced a build process which preprocesses source files prior to the java compiler and resource builders consuming them. (accomplished by creating a build.xml file for the project which runs successfully with ant.)

2 questions ...

1. How do I interactively debug the .apk file (which was produced by my build.xml) in eclipse? (when I push debug, the built in builders run instead of my build.xml)
2. Is there anyway to "hook up" the run/debug convenience buttons in eclipse to my build.xml so that the execution of my build.xml is persued rather than the built-in builders?

Bottom line is I'd like to retain the convenience of getting into an emulator/debug session by pressing the run/debug button, and have those buttons respect my build.xml rather than the built ins.  It's not clear to me how to get the debugger to launch the .apk produced by my build.xml (especially since the .apk is not necessarily named as the builtins produce)

Thank you!

Comment: You described here a solution (a planned solution). What is your problem? Why do you need different APK and build process? Can you tell us some word about it?

Comment: Have you looked at the ant plugins for eclipse?  You can generally get it to use an ant build file instead of its own.